# Why one needs to add 1 when substracting two indexes in order to get the number of elements between those two indexes?

Tags: combinatorics

Why does one need to add 1 when substracting two indexes in order to get the number of elements between those two indexes?

For instance let's consider 4 boxes : `|1|2|3|4|`, between boxes number 2 and 4 one can count 3 boxes, yet `4-2=2`. What causes this phenomenon?

Comment: I only see one number between 2 and 4.

Answer (score 2):

The subtraction counts the number of "hops" it takes to go from one box to the other, or equivalently the number of "bars" `|` between the two boxes. This is always one less than the number of boxes in that range.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you have a sequence $a_1,a_2,\ldots\;$, and you want to know how many terms are strictly between $a_m$ and $a_n$, where $m<n$. From $a_1$ through $a_n$ is $n$ terms:

$$\overbrace{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m,a_{m+1},a_{m+2},\ldots,a_{n-1},a_n}^{n\text{ terms}}$$

The first $m$ of these are the $m$ terms from $a_1$ through $a_m$:

$$\overbrace{\color{crimson}{\underbrace{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m}_{m\text{ terms}}},a_{m+1},a_{m+2},\ldots,a_{n-1},a_n}^{n\text{ terms}}$$

Up through $a_n$ there must therefore be $n-m$ terms after $a_m$:

$$\overbrace{\color{crimson}{\underbrace{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m}_{m\text{ terms}}},\color{blue}{\underbrace{a_{m+1},a_{m+2},\ldots,a_{n-1},a_n}_{n-m\text{ terms}}}}^{n\text{ terms}}$$

But $a_n$ itself is not one of the terms strictly between $a_m$ and $a_n$: we want only the terms from $a_{m+1}$ through $a_{n-1}$, and there are only $n-m-1$ of them.

$$\overbrace{\color{crimson}{\underbrace{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m}_{m\text{ terms}}},\color{green}{\underbrace{a_{m+1},a_{m+2},\ldots,a_{n-1}}_{n-m-1\text{ terms}}},a_n}^{n\text{ terms}}$$

Comment: Great answer thnks doctor scott